# Can someone please explain how c-strings are used in a C++ function call?

Tags: c++, pointers

If I have a function that contains arguments char *a or char *a[], what are the operations I can perform on them within the function?  How do the char pointers work differently than a regular pointer?

Comment: Take a look at string.h document http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is a pointer, no matter what datatype it references.

When you index values from a pointer, the memory it pointer points to is treated as an array of whatever datatype the pointer represents.

A *string* is just an array of characters terminated by a null (zero) character.

You can use the C string library to operate on C strings (`strlen`, `strcpy`, `strcat`, *etc*), and you can easily construct a C++ string object by passing it a `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char*
```

is just a pointer to a character, so anything you can do to pointers you can do to character pointers. The only difference from char* and int* is the type of the pointee.